# Get observable return value without subscribing in calling class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In TypeScript / Angular, you would usually call a function that returns an observable and subscribe to it in a component like this:

```
this.productsService.getProduct().subscribe((product) => { this.product = product });
```

This is fine when the code runs in a class that manages data, but in my opinion this should not be handled in the component. I may be wrong but i think the job of a component should be to ask for and display data without handling how the it is retrieved.

In the angular template you can do this to subscribe to and display the result of an observable:

```
<h1>{{ product.title | async }}</h1>
```

Is it possible to have something like this in the component class? My component displays a form and checks if a date is valid after input. Submitting the form is blocked until the value is valid and i want to keep all the logic behind it in the service which should subscribe to the AJAX call, the component only checks if it got a valid date.

```
 class FormComponent {
    datechangeCallback(date) {
        this.dateIsValid$ = this.dateService.checkDate(date);
    }

    submit() {
        if (this.dateIsValid$ === true) {
            // handle form submission...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you like the observable/subscribe? Would you really prefer your code to block on the potentially long running call to checkDate? If there is data processing involved on the response then you can still put this in the service wrapped in your own Observable. This is the way a single threaded language like JS works so I would recommend getting familiar with Observables, it's certainly neater than the old days of callbacks.

Comment: Hi. My problem is not about subscribing to an observable, it's about subscribing and handling the response in the component. I adds a lot of redundant code which make it less readable. That's why there's an async pipe in the template, it's just too bad it doesn't exist in component classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert rxjs Observables to ES6 Promises and then use the `async-await` syntax to get the data without observable subscription.

**Service:**

```js
export class DateService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  async isDateValid(date): Promise<boolean> {
    let data = await this.http.post(url, date, httpOptions).toPromise();
    let isValid: boolean;
    // perform your validation and logic below and store the result in isValid variable
    return isValid;
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```js
class FormComponent {
    async datechangeCallback(date) {
        this.dateIsValid = await this.dateService.isDateValid(date);
    }

    submit() {
        if (this.dateIsValid) {
            // handle form submission...
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S:**

If this is a simple HTTP request, which completes on receiving one value, then using Promises won't hurt. But if this obersvable produces some continuous stream of values, then using Promises isn't the best solution and you have to revert back to rxjs observables.

Comment: I think that, this is what @Sodium meant, while asking question. But at the same time now preferred way in most cases is Observables.

Comment: @Andris I agree. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, in this case it's a simple AJAX call that is called on input change. This would work altough it's still too much code in the component in my opinion. But how do i handle this on service side? It's a http call (return this.http.post(...)). Thanks.

Comment: Edit: Oups sorry, i still had aync in my function in the service from my trials and errors, it works now thanks.

Comment: @Sodium The best you can do is to move the `toPromise()` call and your logic to the service method. Updated answer to show it.

Comment: Yes this is perfect thanks ;) Been banging my head over this for two days.

Comment: Honestly you can do this but I would caution against avoiding RxJS observables just because you don't like the syntax. Observables can do much more than promises so you are limiting your capabilities. Also RxJs is standard across angular applications so you should expect to learn it if you need to use angular for work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way IMHO, using 7.4.0 < RxJS < 8

```js
import { of, from, tap, firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

const asyncFoo = () => {
  return from(
    firstValueFrom(
      of('World').pipe(
        tap((foo) => {
          console.info(foo);
        })
      )
    )
  );
};

asyncFoo();
// Outputs "World" once

asyncFoo().subscribe((foo) => console.info(foo));
// Outputs "World" twice
```

The "more cleanest" way would be having a factory (in some service) to build these optionally subscribeable function returns...
Something like this:

```js
const buildObs = (obs) => {
  return from(firstValueFrom(obs));
};

const asyncFoo = () => {
  return buildObs(
    of('World').pipe(
      tap((foo) => {
        console.info(foo);
      })
    )
  );
};
```