# Return value in function when service all is complete

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function where I want to return an array. This function makes a service call to my backend so I want to return the array when I know my service call is complete.

```
getList(id: number): MyArray[] {
    let temp: MyArray[] = [];
    this.service.getById(id).subscribe(
      singleId => {
        temp = temp.concat(singleId);
      },
      () => {},
      () => {
        this.myArray= temp;
        return temp;
      }
    );
  }
```

But when I compile my code it still gives me the error

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

If I return `temp` outside of the `subscribe` function, it returns nothing since the service call is not actually complete

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get observable return value without subscribing in calling class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60489200/get-observable-return-value-without-subscribing-in-calling-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the array from `getList`, then it has to be `Observable`, and whatever calls it will subscribe to the returned observable.

If you want to perform an operation, such as pushing the result into an array, you can do this in a `tap` operator in the pipe.

If you want to return the array that you're adding to, you can map to that array.

```js
getList(id: number): Observable<MyArray[]> {
  return this.service.getById(id).pipe(
    tap(single => this.myArray.push(single)),
    map(() => this.myArray)
  );
}
```

This isn't a particularly useful function, but it demonstrates how you return a result from an asynchronous call.